# Typora coverpage title and author from YAML front matters

Tags: javascript, css, editor

I'm trying to autogenerate a cover page using WebKit / JS.

Currently Im printing a title however when I'm trying to export the author it crashes

Current implementation

```js
<meta name="title" content="${title}">
<div id='_export_cover' style="height:100vh;">
  <div id='_export_title' style="margin-top: 25%;text-align: center;font-size: 3rem;">
  <div id='_export_author' style="margin-top: 40%;text-align: center;font-size: 1.5rem;">
  </div>
</div>
<script>
var $cover = document.querySelector("#_export_cover");
var title = document.querySelector("meta[name='title']").getAttribute("content");
var author = document.querySelector("meta[name='author']").getAttribute("content");

if(!title || title == "${title}" || !author || author == "${author}") {
  // no title
  $cover.remove();
} else {
  document.body.insertBefore($cover, document.body.childNodes[0])
  $cover.querySelector("#_export_title").textContent = title;
  $cover.querySelector("#_export_author").textContent = author;
}
</script>
```

Does anyone see the issue with this snippet?

Comment: Any error message logs?

Comment: No, it just skips the rendering of the coverage, not 100% were typora stores additional logs.

Comment: Additional logs, did not provid any additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to run your HTML and found that there is no `meta` tag with `name='author'`

`var author = document.querySelector("meta[name='author']").getAttribute("content");` show error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null`

you should add a meta tag `<meta name="author" content="${author}" />` like this.

Answer (score 1):

**you should add a meta tag**

```
            <meta name="author" content="${author}" />
```

**like this.This will solve your problem.**